# JQuery mouseenter and mouseleave css, isn't working.

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

Trying to make an expanding navigation bar. Did it with css, but failed to stop it from resetting after clicking onto a new page. To fix it, used Jquery. Used mouse enter and mouseleave to try and do it. When using alerts, it worked, but when trying to apply css, it failed to function.

The Jquery

```
                $(function(){
                $("nav").mouseenter(function(){
                    .css({"width": "200px", "overflow": "visible"});
                });

                $("nav").mouseleave(function(){
                    .css({"width": "60px", "overflow": "hidden"});
                });
            });
```

The HTML

```
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>  
            <h1>Chemistry Home</h1>
        </header>


        <nav>
            <div id="logo"> 
                <img  src="Images/Logo.png" >
            </div>                  

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Index.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-HOME fa-2x" id="on"></i>  <!--this is using the font awesome icons, reffered to in the head. Multiple divs are used as the websote declared it should be done. Purely used for the icons -->
                        <span class="nav-text" id="on">
                            HOME
                        </span>
                    </a>                      
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="standards_&_info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            STANDARDS & INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="interesting_info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            INTERESTING INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="JOBS.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            JOBS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="photo_&_video.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            PHOTOS & VIDEOS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="cover">

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="two-box">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Why</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur. Cras ornare nibh vitae justo hendrerit, nec congue metus vulputate. Integer in odio purus. Maecenas et elementum urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur.Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur.Aliquam nec nisi sit amet ligula bibendum dignissim eget eu ex. Praesent ut ex semper, cursus lorem in, maximus eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sed venenatis nisl, quis pretium tortor. Sed lacinia eu leo quis mollis. Pellentesque ut nulla commodo.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sed venenatis nisl, quis pretium tortor. Sed lacinia eu leo quis mollis. Pellentesque ut nulla commodo lorem blandit accumsan sed ac ante. Curabitur scelerisque nec metus rutrum scelerisque. Aliquam a sodales magna. lorem blandit accumsan sed ac ante. Curabitur scelerisque nec metus rutrum scelerisque. Aliquam a sodales magna. Fusce nec sem sem. Praesent eget justo sed ante volutpat malesuada ullamcorper eget eros. Phasellus sodales nisl enim, id tincidunt ligula ultricies sit amet.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="two-box">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Quotes</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur.Cras ornare nibh vitae justo hendrerit, nec congue metus vulputate. Integer in odio purus. Maecenas et elementum urna. Aliquam nec nisi sit amet ligula bibendum dignissim eget eu ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus velit ut nunc pellentesque, sed pretium neque tristique. Nunc pellentesque eros at rhoncus consectetur.Praesent ut ex semper, cursus lorem in, maximus eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sed venenatis nisl, quis pretium tortor. Sed lacinia eu leo quis mollis. Pellentesque ut nulla commodo lorem blandit accumsan sed ac ante. Curabitur scelerisque nec metus rutrum scelerisque. Aliquam a sodales magna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sed venenatis nisl, quis pretium tortor. Sed lacinia eu leo quis mollis. Pellentesque ut nulla commodo lorem blandit accumsan sed ac ante. Curabitur scelerisque nec metus rutrum scelerisque. Aliquam a sodales magna.  Fusce nec sem sem. Praesent eget justo sed ante volutpat malesuada ullamcorper eget eros. Phasellus sodales nisl enim, id tincidunt ligula ultricies sit amet.</p>
                </div>

            </div>              

        </div>


        <footer> 
            rueregrewghe
        </footer>
    </div>          
</body>
```

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8nro6s3/)

It may be probable that its a rookie mistake, I haven't used JQuery before, so if you could help in anyway, it would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.css is no valid standalone expression. you have to use $(this).css. your css is incorrect and your fiddle has no jquery included...

```
            $(function(){
                $("nav").mouseenter(function(){
                    $(this).css({"width": "200px", "overflow": "visible"});
                });

                $("nav").mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).css({"width": "60px", "overflow": "hidden"});
                });
            });
```

corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/h8nro6s3/2/

Answer (score 0):

I did use css rather jquery for simple stuff. You can always use :hover for such stuffs. Have a look.

```
nav:hover {
    width:200px;
    overflow:visible;
    transition:ease 1s;
}
```

[JSfiddle Working](http://jsfiddle.net/h8nro6s3/1/)